# Problema con estilos de componentes

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

Hola estoy usando react por primera vez y soy algo novato pero me lance a experimentar y estoy teniendo un problema, estoy usando algunas librerias para facilitar el estilo de la pagina web como twin.macro styled-components etc, pero tengo un problema: al declarar los items que quiero que aparezcan en la barra de navegacion superior no se le adjuntan algunos estillos como el color de las letras las transiciones de color etc, alguna solucion, adjunto el codigo completo:

```html
import React from "react";
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";
import tw from "twin.macro";
import { slide as Menu } from "react-burger-menu";
import { useMediaQuery } from "react-responsive";
import { SCREENS } from "../responsive";
import menuStyles from "./menuStyles";

const ListContainer = styled.ul`
  ${tw`
    flex
    list-none
  `};
`;

const NavItem = styled.li<{ menu?: any }>`
  ${tw`
    text-sm
    md:text-base
    text-black
    font-medium
    mr-1
    md:mr-5
    cursor-pointer
    transition
    duration-300
    ease-in-out
    hover:text-gray-700
  `};

  ${({ menu }) =>
    menu &&
    css`
      ${tw`
      text-white
      text-xl
      mb-3
      focus:text-white
    `};
    `};
`;

export function NavItems() {
  const isMobile = useMediaQuery({ maxWidth: SCREENS.sm });

  if (isMobile)
    return (
      <Menu right styles={menuStyles}>
        <ListContainer>
          <NavItem menu>
            <a href="/#">Home</a>
          </NavItem>
          <NavItem menu>
            <a href="/#">Nosotros</a>
          </NavItem>
          <NavItem menu>
            <a href="/#">Proyectos</a>
          </NavItem>
          <NavItem menu>
            <a href="/#">Contacto</a>
          </NavItem>
          <NavItem menu>
            <a href="/#">Login</a>
          </NavItem>
        </ListContainer>
      </Menu>
    );

  return (
    <ListContainer>
      <NavItem>
        <a href="/#">Home</a>
      </NavItem>
      <NavItem>
        <a href="/#">Nosotros</a>
      </NavItem>
      <NavItem>
        <a href="/#">Proyectos</a>
      </NavItem>
      <NavItem>
        <a href="/#">Contacto</a>
      </NavItem>
      <NavItem>
        <a href="/#">Login</a>
      </NavItem>
    </ListContainer>
  );
}
```

las sentencias estan puestas en const NavItem pero al llamar al objeto debajo del codigo no se ejecutan los colores por ejemplo pero si se respeta el mr-1 o md:mr-5 por ejemplo, para mi tiene que ver con el anchor predetermiando de html al llamar a  pero no estoy seguro no se por donde indagar y chat gpt no me ayuda de mucho